Why would an arcade script produce values but not symbology in the same Map Viewer profile?
I have a joined view layer in AGOL that contains census tracts with joined characteristics data. The joined view layer opens normally, and can symbolize based on any single field through the map viewer GUI. However, I am encountering an issue when trying to define symbology with Arcade. The script more or less iterates over a number of columns in the characteristics data and sums them to produce a percentage that I am attempting to symbolize with. The script is as follows:
var tot = $feature.U7T001 + $feature.U7U001 + $feature.U7V001 + $feature.U7W001 + $feature.U7X001 + $feature.U70001;
var popArrays = ['T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', '0'];
var agingPop = 0;
for(var x in popArrays){
  var age = 17;
  while(age<26){
    var grab = `U7${popArrays[x]}0${Text(age)}`;
    if(IsEmpty($feature[grab])){
      age +=1;
    }else{
      agingPop += $feature[grab];
      age += 1;
    }
  }
  age = 41;
  while(age<50){
    var grab = `U7${popArrays[x]}0${Text(age)}`;
    if(IsEmpty($feature[grab])){
      age += 1;
    }else{
      agingPop += $feature[grab];
      age += 1;
    }
  }
}


var percAging = Round((agingPop/tot)*100, 1)
return percAging

I have verified this script is functioning as intended by performing the run test in the symbology expression IDE as well as putting the same script out to the pop up. However, for some reason map viewer is not recognizing the data for symbology and even shows as if there is no data (see pictures). Specifically, when using the "High-to-Low" symbology, the GUI shows no values, and a 0 st. dev. Indicating it is not interpreting any data. However, the GUI is automatically detecting that the output is a float and selecting this "High-to-Low" symbology by default.


I have also attempted to treat the value into buckets to utilize the inherent "Unique Values" symbology, however when doing this, it would only symbolize every thing as "Other." Here is a code snippet of what that additional code looked like:
if(percAging<10){
    return "0.0% - 9.9%";
}else if(percAging<20){
    return "10.0% - 19.9%"
}...

At face value, this appears to be a simple and straight forward Arcade Symbolization, but I clearly am having some issue I cannot identify. Have I used some sort of syntax or logic that isn't supported for the symbology profile? Is this a bug?
